# how to display multiple rows in one row with same id in mysql?

Tags: mysql, select

i have a view in mysql and i want to show two rows with the same id in one row.  Please see following pic :

[image]

**please help me : i want to show *expr1* column in one column**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT POST_ID,TITLE,USERNAME,DATE_TIME,COMMENT_COUNT,GROUP_CONCAT(Expr1) as Expr1
FROM TableName
GROUP BY POST_ID,TITLE,USERNAME,DATE_TIME,COMMENT_COUNT
```

Result will be:

```
POST_ID  TITLE         USERNAME   DATE_TIME                 COMMENT_COUNT   Expr1
1        HELLO WORLD   AMIN       2014-01-01 00:00:00.000   0               OS,windows xp
```

Answer (score 0):

As it seems data in all other columns are matching, grouping by `id` may work.
But it is always suggested to `group by` those columns that are chosen in `select`

```
select 
  post_id, title, 
  username, date_time, 
  comment_count, 
  group_concat( expr1 separator ' ' ) Expr1
from table_name
group by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 -- positions of columns in the select
```